# How to associate network load balancer to a target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a target group and a network load balance on AWS Console. Now I want to associate both resources via terraform.

The following code should do that:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test" {
    target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:12345:targetgroup/test-tg/c3a301edff7c8274"
    target_id = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:12345:loadbalancer/net/test-nlb/05019d0fbcc689ad"
}
```

But it's throwing me the error:

> Error: registering targets with target group: ValidationError: >'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:12345:loadbalancer/net/test-nlb/05019d0fbcc689ad' is not a valid Application Load Balancer ARN

I have checked my provider configuration and looks ok:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Any idea what is missing to create the association?

Comment: Could you add the resource for the load balancer to the question also?

Answer (score 1):

The `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` resource is for adding *targets* to a target group. This would be for adding down-stream targets such as EC2 instances that the load balancer would send traffic to.

To "associate" a target group with a load balancer you configure one of the load balancer's listeners to send traffic to the target group. You do this either by specifying the target group in the [alb_lb_listener](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener) default action, or in an [aws_lb_listener_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule) action. The load balancer listener resource has both a `load_balancer_arn` attribute, and a `target_group_arn` attribute (inside the default action block), which is what associates the target group to the load balancer.